# Why I have 403 error ONLY when I am using BurpSuite?

Tags: web-testing, penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

during pentesting SOME site I have faced with file upload errors. It is 403 error Forbidden but the most interesting thing lies in the fact it is happening ONLY when I use burp proxy.
When I am uploading passport/id document as a usual way(withou Burp Suite) - No error. 200 OK.
When I am uploading with Burp Suite - 403 Error.

P.S.: Other site functionality/APIs work properly when I use Burp Suite

I have no idea why this 403 error occurs. Is this a bug or a kind of "protection"?

Comment: 403 means its trying to get in but is denied access for some kind of authentication reason.  Check the file rights for the directory you are trying to upload.  You might assume you have the rights, but somewhere you do not.

Answer (score 1):

Then you don't have the authorization to set up a proxy in your OS.
I guess you are using your corporate laptop. Try to change you network settings in your browser. If they are grey out then your organization has blocked that for you ( Bgroup rules).

I faced the same issue exactly and this was the problem.
Hope that helps.